# Sequential swaps on dexes

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, swaps

I wrote a smart contract in solidity to swap ERC20 tokens on different exchanges, however I'm still stuck on how to get my transaction to go from one dex to another without having to use my smart contract as a middleman.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to exclude your contract as the middleman.
DEXes contracts should implement this functionality.
Bancor can offer it, but only for his pairs.